# Get Unique Dates from an Array of Date Stamps

Tags: javascript

I have an array of date stamps:

```
let dateList = [ "2019-07-22T08:40:33.537Z", "2019-07-22T08:40:33.537Z", "2019-07-23T12:02:53.143Z", "2019-07-23T12:02:53.143Z", "2019-07-23T12:12:00.434Z", "2019-07-23T12:12:54.649Z", "2019-07-23T12:14:57.547Z", "2019-07-23T12:14:57.547Z", "2019-07-23T12:16:45.011Z", "2019-07-23T12:16:45.011Z", "2019-07-23T12:21:20.527Z", "2019-07-23T12:24:30.095Z", "2019-07-23T12:25:33.251Z", "2019-07-23T12:27:53.809Z", "2019-07-23T12:27:53.809Z" ]
```

And I need to get the list of unique dates from it. The following function allows me to remove duplicates.

```
let uniqueDates = [...new Set(dateList)];
```

However, it's still an array of unique time stamps. What I really need is an array of unique dates. So, if there are two timestamps of the same date, I need only one in the unique array. Can you please help how I can achieve that?

Comment: So, you just want to ignore the time component and keep only the date part?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the `dateList` to contain only the dates (removing the time portion):

```js
let dateList = [ "2019-07-22T08:40:33.537Z", "2019-07-22T08:40:33.537Z", "2019-07-23T12:02:53.143Z", "2019-07-23T12:02:53.143Z", "2019-07-23T12:12:00.434Z", "2019-07-23T12:12:54.649Z", "2019-07-23T12:14:57.547Z", "2019-07-23T12:14:57.547Z", "2019-07-23T12:16:45.011Z", "2019-07-23T12:16:45.011Z", "2019-07-23T12:21:20.527Z", "2019-07-23T12:24:30.095Z", "2019-07-23T12:25:33.251Z", "2019-07-23T12:27:53.809Z", "2019-07-23T12:27:53.809Z" ]

const uniqueDates = [...new Set(
  dateList
    .map((str) => str.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)[0])
)];
console.log(uniqueDates);
```